# Using Graph API to query SharePoint list items and expand user field

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to query for some SP list items, all is working fine except I can't seem to expand a custom column of type Person.

I can see the `createdBy` and `lastModifiedBy` expanded and even includes the AAD user id, which is great and also leads me to think what I want is possible!

But mine is a custom column.

I'm running this and can only seem to get the SP user list id and the user's display name...neither of which are much use.

```
/items?expand=fields(select=UserLookupId,User)
```

Ideally I'd like to get the AAD user id as per createdBy and modifiedBy field, but the email would suffice.
Otherwise the only way I can see is to query the `User Information List` (using the `UserLookupId`) to get the email?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be correct assumption:

> Otherwise the only way I can see is to query the User Information List
>   (using the UserLookupId) to get the email?

for *non-system* user fields, it is indeed a way to go, but there are some distinctions whether user field is *multi-valued* or *single-valued*. 
If `Approvers` is a multi-valued user field, then the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields($select=Approvers)
```

returns `email` and `id` properties  along with `displayName` property for user field value.

While for  *single-valued user field* **only** `id` (available via `{userfield}LookupId` property) and `displayName` properties could be requested via [items endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0), for example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields($select=Approver,ApproverLookupId)
```

---

So, indeed `User Information List` needs to be utilized to request additional user properties, for example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists('User Information List')/items/{item-id}/?$expand=fields($select=Email)
```

where `item-id` corresponds to *user field lookup id*

Comment: OK, thanks.  It's been a while and no one has come with something better.  So I'll accept and go with this, in the hope it will improve at a later date!

Answer (score 0):

This was my experience modifying the 
[Build Angular single-page apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular).  In the examples below, I changed my id's out with the default text.

Here is 
[The Finished Project on thier github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-angularspa/tree/master/demos/03-add-msgraph)

In **Graph Explorer**, this **worked**.  You can verify it at the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields($select=id,Title)
```

In the **app/graph.service.ts** in the app, this did **not work**.  Even though you would expect it to based on the graph explorer.

```
.api('/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?fields($select=id,Title)')
```

Changing the **app/graph.service.ts** api call **worked**.

```
.api('/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?')
.expand('fields($select=id,Title)')
```

The result looked like this:

```
fields: {
    @odata.etag: ""d6f5b6ea-9f90-452d-98ba-e838f58d3359,1"", 
    Title: "IT SPECIALIST (MID)", 
    id: "20"
}
```

Here's an example site id:

```
some.sharepoint.com,9dk062b-2e54-4e4f-b71a-cdb74f42cc44,c6cf6b0a-cc7c-41fd-a76a-ef8f97e8a22f
```

Here's an example list id.

```
8eg8c29a-5555-4cfc-bfa4-0e907488f781
```

The end url won't have any {} in it.

Comment: I use your same ?expand=fields(select=id,Title) and get ""error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": "The expression \"fields(select\" is not valid.","  Did something change in Graph?